# Nginx REGEX for too long file names

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to filter out too long file names in the Nginx configuration file.

Sometimes bots try to access my Nginx server with too long file names (longer than 255 bytes) what causes a "File name too long" error on Ubuntu.

```
https://myserver.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/123456789...255.html
```

I tried this, but it also counts in the directories the query string:

```
location ~* /[^/].{255,}$ {
  deny all;
}
```

What do I have to change to count only the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex, which should do excalty what you want:

`[^/]{255,}$`

matching 255 characters or more which are not `/` at the end of the line.

Comment: It's also important to enclose the whole expression in quotes!